# Double click executable file and nothing happens

Tags: executable, games

I'm trying to install a game for Linux called Myth 2. Autorun doesn't run when I insert the CD. When I double-click or right-click and the select "Open" on the Setup file, a box appears saying that it's an executable file, and what I want to do. I click on "Run", but nothing happens after that. I checked the permissions, and it allows it running the executable.

How do I install this game? Please break down instructions as much as possible, I'm not used to using commands and Terminal. ;)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Natty? Is it 32 or 64 bit? If you goto a Terminal and type the name of the executable it should give some additional error messages. Need more information to properly troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm running 11.04. I typed the name of the executable and it said "command not found". I'm trying to go to the CD directory in the terminal, but I'm not that proficient. From what I can tell, the name of the CD is Myth2 Soulbligher-Linux, but the terminal says "Myth2: no such file or directory".

Comment: Does the cd you've purchased have a linux version of the game?

Comment: `Autorun doesn't run when I insert the CD.` That's intentional, there is no real `Autorun` feature on Linux like that one in Windows (thank godness). Open up a terminal, navigate to the folder the CD is mounted (you can see the path in Nautilus), and run `./NameOfSetupFileHere`.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, and pardon my ignorance, but can you walk me through this like I'm an 8-year-old? How do I find the path in Nautilus?

Comment: How do I use the Terminal to list all of the directories I can change to? I must be typing the wrong directory name.

Comment: @RalfTiede Use the `ls` command.

Comment: @DoR Hmm... that didn't show me the directories. This is what appeared: `ralf@ubuntu:~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Ubuntu One
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates  Videos
ralf@ubuntu:~$`

Answer (score 2):

What your system needs it to run the game using a Windows type environment.

To get this follow this instruction here:

To install Wine in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal, open Terminal and run the following commands:

For the latest Wine 1.3.xx (Most recent versions but kind of unstable) -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

After which you should reboot. Insert the CD and run the game.